# How to show only trailing decimals if they are all not zeros?

Tags: python, string, decimal

I want to convert the value of a decimal to a string, but only show the trailing decimals if they're not all zeros. e.g. 
`nice_decimal_show(Decimal("3.00")) == "3" nice_decimal_show(Decimal("3.14")) == "3.14"`

What would be the canonical way of doing this?

Right now I'm doing:

````
format_decimal_to_integer_string_if_possible(Decimal("3.000")) "3" >;>;>; format_decimal_to_integer_string_if_possible(Decimal("3.400")) "3.400" """ assert isinstance(decimal, Decimal) integral = decimal.to_integral() if integral == decimal: return str(integral) else: return str(decimal) ```
````

Comment: What even is that code? It isn't valid python.

Answer (score 3):

The best way is to use `g` formatting, rather than `f` formatting.  This will suppress trailing fractional zeroes.  For example:

```
>>> print("%g" % 3.0)
3
>>> 
>>> print("%g" % 3.0012)
3.0012
>>>
```

You can also use `g` in `format` strings:

```
>>> print("{:g}".format(3.0))
3
>>> 
>>> print("{:g}".format(3.0012))
3.0012
>>>
```

If you want to limit the precision, you can use:

```
>>> print("%.4g" % 3.0012)
3.001
>>>
```

or

```
>>> print("{:.4g}".format(3.0012))
3.001
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

I like this way of doing it:

```
('%f' % Decimal("3.000")).rstrip('0').rstrip('.')
```

I don't know if it's the canonical way of doing it though...